# REGEXP and operator .+

Tags: regex, mysql-5.0

I am trying to use MySql REGEXP to find rows where `green` **and** `2012` occurs in the column

I am using `.+` in the regexp.

This works:

```
select  'green 2012-01' REGEXP 'green.+2012'
```

returns `1`

but if I place the '2012' first it returns 0

```
select  'green 2012-01' REGEXP '2012.+green';
```

returns `0`

I am using MYSQL Software version: 5.1.43 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: This is probably an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  What are you *really* trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are kinda order dependent. What you'll need to do is put an | (or) operator between your two items to make it look for either one.

```
select 'green 2012-01' REGEXP '(green.*2012)|(2012.*green)'
```

Comment: **+1** - this is correct, though you don't really need all those brackets.

Comment: Thanks for that - I tried it - worked but then I removed the space and it didn't work - select 'green2012-01' REGEXP '(green.+2012)|(2012.+green)'

Comment: You'll want to use .* (0 or more somethings) instead of .+ (1 or more somethings). I've edited my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: How would I search for three strings e.g 'green' and '2012' and 'London'

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `REGEX`, while potentially less efficient, you could simply use [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) twice.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOCATE('2012', column) AND LOCATE('green', column);
```

Comment: I am dynamically constructing the query using an input box to get the the search string. The user would enter 20012^green and I convert it to 2012.+green. It works when green^2012 is entered

Comment: Are you ultimately searching for each string the user enters?

Comment: I concatenate the columns of a table and run a query searching for the string the user has entered e.g green^2012. The user would be trying to find a row that has both green and 2012 in it.

Comment: `LOCATE` is still applicable in this case. The logic for parsing user input is beyond SQL.